# Overloaded operator in while loop or something else? C++ Beginner here

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I am following the OOP in C++ book by Bruce Eckel. I am on chapter 2 exercises. The exercise in question asks the following

"Create a program that counts the occurrence of a
particular word in a file"

There are multiple ways to achieve this such as create a helper function that reads the file content into a string. I did it with while loop and the [string find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) method. However, the suggested solutions from the book gave a rather elegant solution that I don't understand. Full disclosure: I am not enrolled in any class. I am doing this for my own understanding :)

```
/**
Create a program that counts the occurrence of a particular word in a file
(use the string class’ operator ‘==’ to find the word).
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int counter = 0;
    string key;

    cout << "Please enter the word for search: ";
    cin >> key;

    ifstream inputFile("04.txt");
    string buf;

    while (inputFile >> buf) {

        if (key == buf)
            ++counter;
    }

    cout << "Word " << key << " occurs " << counter << " time(s)." << endl;


return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is the while loop.

```
    while (inputFile >> buf) {

        if (key == buf)
            ++counter;
    }
```

First the program requests the user the input to find then opens the txt file using fstream and then created a string called buf. So far so good but I don't understand while (inputFile >> buf) at all. What I gather from the documentation is that this is the either an overloaded operator or [this operator being inherited from istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). However, I am just guessing now.

Can someone please explain what is going on in that while loop? What does while (inputFile >> buf) mean? C++ beginner here so please be kind.

Comment: There is also an inherited `operator bool`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ender's answer is not so helpful so let me provide you with this [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/). It's from `string's operator>>` official documentation and it states there that:

> Notice that the istream extraction operations use whitespaces as
>   separators; Therefore, this operation will only extract what can be
>   considered a word from the stream.

So while you were trying to see `istream operator>>`, in your example code the `string's operator>>` was actually executed.

To sum this up, the operator>> reads from the input stream word by word (delimited by white space) and it will return true if something was read from there.

Comment: You are awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since inputFile is an istream, this is taking input from the file and putting it in the buf. Also, if you have `genericIstream >> str` it will return a boolean indicating if the genericIstream is empty. In this case, the while loop continues until all of the file has been read.